# How can I move values between properties of an object in Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have the following object:

```
var player = {
  cards: [1,2,3,4,5],
  hand: []
}
```

I want to move some items of the `cards` property into `hand`.

I though of using lenses to keep from mutating the object, but could not arrive at a solution that would allow me to do it just composing functions. Maybe it's not supposed to be done that way.

The best I could do is as following:

```
function drawIntoHand(amount, player) {
  const deck = R.lensProp('cards')
  const hand = R.lensProp('hand')

  let cardsRemoved = R.over(deck, R.take(amount), player)
  R.set(hand, R.append(cardsRemoved), player)
  return R.set(deck, R.drop(amount), player)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to move cards by index or by value?

Comment: Everything is possible by composing functions (as lambda calculus tells us), but it's not necessarily declarative.

Comment: Why are you ignoring the result of `R.set(hand, R.append(cardsRemoved), player)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one version:

```
const drawIntoHand = (() => {
  const deck = lensProp('cards');
  const hand = lensProp('hand');

  return (amount, player) => {
    const draw = take(amount, view(deck, player));
    return over(deck, drop(amount), over(hand, concat(draw), player));
  };
})();

drawIntoHand(3, player); //=> {"cards": [4, 5], "hand": [1, 2, 3]}
```

But I wouldn't even attempt to make something like this points-free.  I'm not sure how I could do it, but if I could, I'm quite certain it would be much harder to read.

You can see it in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.19.1#?code=let%20player%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20cards%3A%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%2C%0A%20%20hand%3A%20%5B%5D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20drawIntoHand%20%3D%20%28%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20deck%20%3D%20lensProp%28%27cards%27%29%3B%0A%20%20const%20hand%20%3D%20lensProp%28%27hand%27%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20return%20%28amount%2C%20player%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20draw%20%3D%20take%28amount%2C%20view%28deck%2C%20player%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20over%28deck%2C%20drop%28amount%29%2C%20over%28hand%2C%20concat%28draw%29%2C%20player%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%29%28%29%3B%0A%0AdrawIntoHand%283%2C%20player%29%3B%0A)**.